# Dynamic table of buttons

Tags: dynamic

Suppose I start with a list

```
list ={{1,2},{3,4}};
```

I would like to have a table of buttons of the same form, starting with labels 1,2,3,4. By pressing each button, an input would ask for a new value of that button, and the button labels (and list) would dynamically change. I have tried

```
Dynamic[Column[
  Table[ButtonBar[
    Table[list[[i, j]] :> 
              (str = Input["blah"]; 
               list[[i, j]] = str), 
         {j, 1, 2}], 
       Method -> "Queued"], 
  {i, 1, 2}]]]
```

But this gives me [image]

I sort of understand the error. Any idea how to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: try `Dynamic[Column[
  Table[With[{i = i}, 
    ButtonBar[Table[With[{j = j}, list[[i, j]] :> (str = Input["blah"];
         list[[i, j]] = str)], {j, 1, 2}], Method -> "Queued"]], {i, 
    1, 2}]]]`?

Comment: This seems to be doing the trick, thanks!